# How do you insert the site name into a default asset path?

Tags: assets, multi-site, assets-field

Multisite question.... how do I output the site into the assets path? currentSite won't work because its the admin panel, so the current site is always the default site.

Using the below, I will always get `/default/footer-content` with this, regardless of which site is having its field edited.

[image]

Comment: So, I got this to work accounting for the ?site=foo parameter in entries and the /admin/globals/foo/globalsethandle formats used in globals .... but this feels ultra fragile. 

`{{ craft.request.getParam('site')|length ? craft.request.getParam('site') : craft.request.getSegment(2) }}/footer-content`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `{site.handle}` instead of `{{currentSite.handle}}` and it should work ok.

Comment: Here are the docs on the "object syntax" used for Entry URI formats: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#entry-uri-formats - The answer given above is a shortcut for `{object.site.handle}` - good to know if you ever need to use entry data in the URI - it's all accessible under the `object` variable.